# How to add a search filter with scope to Searchkick? (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5 and the Searchkick gem.

I'm using this now in my controller, and it works fine:

```
@blogs = Blog.search(query, where:{published_at: nil})
```

But I would like to use a scope that is NOT nil, so:

```
 scope :published, ->{ where.not(published_at: nil )}
```

But I don't know how to make it work in my controller, I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
 @blogs = Blog.search(query, where.not:{published_at: nil})
```

How to get those records that are not nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
@blogs = Blog.search(query, where: { published_at: { not: nil } })
```

Source: [Searchkick ~ Querying](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying)